# Is there a function to find the amount bytes currently loaded from a file with XMLHtttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, loading

I'm trying to write a loading screen using the file size and the amount of bytes loaded from the file. I'm able to get the file size with the `XmlHttpRequest.getResponseHeader ("Content-Length")` but I want to get the size of the file loaded **so far** in order for me to write a function that will update a `<div>` on my my webpage to show the percentage loaded so far.

Is there a function similar to `.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")` that will return the **current** amount of the file loaded instead of the total file size?

Cheers,
Dez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttRequest.responseText.length will probably be correct.

You will need to make sure you get the value when `onreadystatechange == 3` to get the amount of bytes loaded so far. you can then use that data to calculate your loading screen. If you use it when `onreadystatechange == 4` it will give you the amount of bytes of the whole file and not the bytes sent so far.

Comment: If the `Trasfer-Encoding: chunked` header is set, you can use `xhr.onprogress = function() { alert(xhr.response.length); };`, for instance.